# Python/Facebook-SDk How to get shares count for a photo posted on a page

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have a facebook page where i post photos, they appear on the timeline. I see button there, near 'like' and 'comment', 'share'. and i see count for how many times this item was shared. How can i get this count?

Things i tried:

```
img_id_on_facebook = '123'
fb = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
fb.request(path='/123/shares')
```

This gives:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Another try:

```
fb.request(path='/123/', args={'fields': 'shares'})
```

Gives same error.

Calling:

```
fb.request(path='/123/')
```

Has no key 'shares'.

I also tried the fql:

```
fb.fql('SELECT shares_count FROM link_stat WHERE url=https://facebook.com/123')
```

This gives:

```
GraphAPIError: Impersonated access tokens can only be used with the Graph API
```

I also tried:

```
fb.request(path='/[PAGE_ID]_[PHOTO ID]/')
```

This gives error: no such endpoint.

Anyone knows how can i get the number of shares for a photo? Is there a way at all?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the post id which should be of the form `pageid_postedid`. For example for this photo

`https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151690351123254&set=a.100690783253.87226.80329313253&type=1&theater`

The id of the photo is `10151690351123254`
The id of the page is `80329313253`

The post_id is `80329313253_10151690351363254`

So then you can request the shares as `80329313253_10151690351363254?fields=shares`

```
{
  "shares": {
    "count": 4435
  }, 
  "id": "80329313253_10151690351363254", 
  "created_time": "2013-06-19T18:02:31+0000"
}
```

Or in your case in Python something like

```
fb.request(path='/80329313253_10151690351363254', args={'fields': 'shares'})
```

Comment: i tried this in graph api tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=340838642686446_352899518147025%3Ffields%3Dshares. it returns an error: no such endpoint.

Comment: @Neara no such post or photo exists. I don't know where you got that from... your list of posts can be found at `340838642686446/posts`

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Test-Page/340838642686446/posts this gives 404.

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=352899518147025&set=a.340839579353019.1073741825.340838642686446&type=1 this is where i take this image from.

Comment: @Neara you need to find it via the API.... graph.facebook.com/340838642686446/posts. Also I cannot see that post.

Comment: the id's im using come from graph api, its one of the few details you get back after successful post. i checked graph.facebook.com/340838642686446/posts it does show an object for a photo, with the id i used so far, has comments and likes,but no shares. i know it should have shares cos i shared it. i a post saying so, and appropriate count, but i dont see the number through graph api

Comment: @Neara pastebin the response you get from graph.facebook.com/340838642686446/posts because I don't see it.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/neara/5845729 you can see a sample here, it goes on and on.

https://gist.github.com/neara/5845734 this is the object that was shared.

Comment: @Neara I would file a bug that link isn't publicly available even though the privacy settings state it as such.

Comment: Works for me, here is my example: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=241897672509479_657303980968844%3Ffields%3Dshares%2Clikes